# Почему False and str возвращает False, но True and str возвращает str?

Tags: python

Понимаю, что в Python применются ленивые вычисления, но мне кажется это настоящие грабли. Вот реальный пример: (sqlalchemy_migrate)

```
funcname = upgrade and "upgrade" or "downgrade"
```

То есть в зависимости от значения upgrade (True или False), переменная получит соответствующее имя. С ходу довольно сложно понять, что вернет такое выражение. Кроме того, bool and str может вернуть как bool, так и str, в зависимости от того, чему равен bool. Считаете ли вы такой подход рациональным?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Насколько я понимаю, у Вас нет вопроса, как именно вычисляется выражение в примере, но все же напишу.
Т.к. приоритет `and` и `or` одинаков, и эти операторы левоассоциативны, то

```
upgrade and "upgrade" or "downgrade"
```

эквивалентно

```
(upgrade and "upgrade") or "downgrade"
```

Первым вычисляем выражение в скобках, оно равно `False` если `upgrade == False`(1), или `"upgrade"`, если `upgrade == True`(2). В итоге имеем

```
(1) False or "downgrade" --> "downgrade"
(2) "upgrade" or "downgrade" --> "upgrade" (т.к. "upgrade" - истинно)
```

---

П.С. Лично мне именно эта строчка также кажется не слишком читаемой. Вообще, здесь явно напрашивается использование тернарного оператора, который имеется в Питоне, хотя и синтаксически отличается от тернарного оператора в большинстве других языков:

```
funcname = "upgrade" if upgrade else "downgrade"
```

Это всего на один символ длиннее, но бывают случаи, когда подобная запись действительно удобна и читаема:

```
do_something() or do_something_else()
```

`do_something_else` выполнится только в том случае, если `do_something` вернет `False` (например, что-то пошло не так). Это, фактически, стандартная идиома для языка `perl`, в Питоне я что-то подобное встречал значительно реже.

Answer (score 3):

Понять, что вернет логическое выражение довольно таки несложно:

- `a and b` возвращает `a`, если `a` ложно, и `b` в противном случае.
- `a or b` возвращает `a`, если `a` истино, и `b` в противном случае.

Следующие объекты считаются ложными:

- `None`
- `False`
- нулевые значения числовых типов (`0`, `0L`, `0.0`, `0j`)
- пустые последовательности (`''`, `[]`, `()`)
- пустой словарь (`{}`)
- объект user-defined класса, реализующий метод `__nonzero__`, который возвращает `0` или `False`, или не реализующий метод `__nonzero__`, но реализующий метод `__len__`, возвращающий `0`

Во всех остальных случаях объект считается истинным.

Answer (score 2):

```
funcname = upgrade and "upgrade" or "downgrade"
```

эквивалентно:

```
funcname = "upgrade" if upgrade else "downgrade"
```

Или (для полной ясности):

```
if upgrade:
    funcname = "upgrade"
else:
    funcname = "downgrade"
```

В тех случаях когда используется динамическое выражение вместо `"upgrade"` константы, `and-or` выражение может сломаться, поэтому предпочительней всегда использовать `if-else` конструкцию в коде на современных версиях Питона, которые поддерживает эту конструкцию (Python 2.6+, Python 3).

Пример, когда and-or ломается:

```
>>> True and 0 or "broken"
'broken'
>>> 0 if True else "works"
0
```

Чтобы понять какие Питон-объекты в if-условии эквивалентны `True`, see [Truth Value Testing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth).

Так называемое [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) достаточно распространено в программировании, поэтому следует научиться понимать подобные конструкции.

Во всех случаях возвращаются сами объекты (а не их boolean значения):

```
>>> "" and 1/0
''
```

Пустая строка возвращается потому что `bool("") is False` в Питоне. `1/0` не вычисляется (short-circuit) -- иначе бы `ZeroDivisionError` мы бы увидели.